# Running sh/bash/python scripts with arguments using Go

Tags: linux, bash, shell, go

I've been stuck on this one a few days, I'm trying to run a bash script which runs off of the first argument (maybe I should give up all hope, haha)

Syntax for running the script can be assumed to be:

`sudo bash script argument` or since it has og+x it can be ran as just `sudo script argument`

In go I'm running it using the following:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    c := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "script " + argument)
    if err := c.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

I have had absolutely no luck, I've tried loads of other variations as well for this...

`exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "sudo script", argument)`

`exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "sudo script " + argument)` (my first try)

`exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "sudo script" + argument)`

`exec.Command("/bin/bash", "sudo script", argument)`

`exec.Command("/bin/bash sudo script" + argument)`

Most of these I am met with '/bin/bash sudo ect' no such file or directory, or `Error:  exit status 1` I have even gone as far as to write a Python wrapper looking for an argument and executing the bash script with subprocess.  To rule out the path to the script not being defined I have tried all of the above with a direct route to the script rather than script name.

For the sake of my remaining hair, what am I doing wrong here? How can I better diagnose this problem so that I can get more information rather than exit status 1?

Comment: '/bin/bash sudo ect' would be incorrect - you could run a script this way, but not a binary executable (which sudo is). Invocation with -c option should do - but as you write that you tried that too, there's probably an additional problem. What's the error with -c?  and what if you invoke sudo directly, without bash? Can you /bin/bash name_of_a_script   execute that script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call bash/sh at all, simply pass each argument alone, also to get the error you have to capture the command's stderr, here's a working example:

```
func main() {
    c := exec.Command("sudo", "ls", "/tmp")
    stderr := &bytes.Buffer{}
    stdout := &bytes.Buffer{}
    c.Stderr = stderr
    c.Stdout = stdout
    if err := c.Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err, "|", stderr.String())
    } else {
        fmt.Println(stdout.String())
    }
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this, with the added information from the error I'm getting: Error:  exit status 1 | sudosh: couldn't get your controlling terminal.  So the bash script is calling sudosh and can't find my terminal due to I assume the way go is calling it

Comment: You just need to use `c := exec.Command("sudo", "script", argument)`

Comment: That is what's being ran.. `c := exec.Command("sudo", "path/to/script", argument)`   both `/path/to/script` and `script` yield the same

Comment: You'd have to use a fake terminal, has nothing to do with the way Go is calling it, some apps require a pty to operate, that'd be a different question with a very long answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @OneOfOne this helps a lot.  <- that sounds sarcastic, it's not meant to